# Create attributed text of placeholder's values in a String

Tags: swift, nsattributedstring

I got this `String`:

```
let someString = String(format: NSLocalizedString("%1$@ changed your user role %2$@.", comment: ""), username, userRole)
```

I want to make the `userRole` bold. That could be done with a `NSMutableAttributedString`. To accomplish that task, I think need to create ranges of the replaced text. I don't know how to do that, other than adding tags, like HTML tags to identify the placeholders. I don't want to use tags because that would require client/server-side validations and more.

Is there any way I can obtain the second argument's replaced text range? Simply searching for the placeholder in `someString` isn't sufficient, because if, for example, the user role equals a translated text before the placeholder, I get a wrong range.

I want to have a future and user proof way to make placeholder text attributed.

Answer (score 0):

I've had to do this exact thing before, for convenience reasons. My strategy was to make a subclass of `UILabel`, and then override the `text` member, modify the text, and set the `attributedText` of the label (effectively overwriting the original text). Like so:

```
/// Custom label that autoformats its text content. Use "@" to denote bolded ranges.
class AutoformatLabel: UILabel {

    // The special char that denotes bolded ranges.
    private let kSpecialChar: String = "@"
    // Set your font size and which fonts you want to use for bold/regular, here.
    var boldedFont = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18.0)
    var regularFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18.0)


    /// Usage:
    ///     label.text = "Regular text @bolded text@ back to regular"
    public override var text: String? {
        didSet {
            let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "")
            let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
            // Add things like line spacing, etc. to your paragraphStyle here, if desired.
            paragraphStyle.alignment = self.textAlignment
            let phrases = text!.split(separator: kSpecialChar)
            for i in 0...(phrases.count - 1) {
                let attPhrase = NSMutableAttributedString(string: String(phrases[i]))
                if i % 2 != 0 {
                    attPhrase.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.font, value: boldedFont, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attPhrase.length))
                } else {
                    attPhrase.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.font, value: regularFont, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attPhrase.length))
                }
                attributedText.append(attPhrase)
            }
            attributedText.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle, value: paragraphStyle, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedText.length - 1))
            self.attributedText = attributedText
        }
    }

}
```

You can change which char you want to use to denote bolded ranges by setting the constant `kSpecialChar` to whatever you like. Hope that helps!

---

**EDIT:** Misread the question! Here's the chunk of code that you're looking for:

```
let text = "changed your user role"
let boldedText = "user"
let boldedRange = text.range(of: "user")
let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
attributedText.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.font, value: boldedFont, range: NSRange(location: boldedRange.lowerBound, length: boldedRange.upperBound - boldedRange.lowerBound))

myLabel.attributedText = attributedText
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I explicitly stated that I don't want to use tags inside my text, because that requires extra validations, constraints etc. Do you have a solution without using a special tag?

Comment: Ah, I thought you meant html tags! Why does it require extra validations?

Comment: You can't accept any more usernames/messages/any text input that contains any (HTML) tag on any supporting platform and database without having the risk that the ranges will be corrupted. That is ugly and hard to maintain. Maybe there is a more generic solution.

Comment: The above solution did not use any html tags. I just use a character, "@", to make things simple. Edited the answer above though, with what you're looking for.